# How to Replace constructor with initComponent in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am trying to run [this](http://jsfiddle.net/existdissolve/dkJb9/) (http://jsfiddle.net/existdissolve/dkJb9/) example in my Extjs Project . But I have read the we can replace 
constructor with initComponent  as initComponent  is better to use . but when I replace the constructor with initComponent the example does not run . how can I replace constructor with initComponent in the example with still the same functionality.

```
Ext.define('Ext.chart.series.AutoGroupedColumn', {
    extend: 'Ext.chart.series.Column',
    type: 'autogroupedcolumn',
    alias: 'series.autogroupedcolumn',
    gField: null,
    constructor: function( config ) {
        this.callParent( arguments );
        // apply any additional config supplied for this extender
        Ext.apply( this, config );
        var me = this,
            store = me.chart.getStore(),
            // get groups from store (make sure store is grouped)
            groups = store.isGrouped() ? store.getGroups() : [],
            // collect all unique values for the new grouping field
            groupers = store.collect( me.gField ),
            // blank array to hold our new field definitions (based on groupers collected from store)
            fields = [];
        // first off, we want the xField to be a part of our new Model definition, so add it first
        fields.push( {name: me.xField } );
        // now loop over the groupers (unique values from our store which match the gField)
        for( var i in groupers ) {
            // for each value, add a field definition...this will give us the flat, in-record column for each group 
            fields.push( { name: groupers[i], type: 'int' } );
        }
        // let's create a new Model definition, based on what we determined above
        Ext.define('GroupedResult', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: fields
        });
        // now create a new store using our new model
        var newStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'GroupedResult'
        });
        // now for the money-maker; loop over the current groups in our store
        for( var i in groups ) {
            // get a sample model from the group
            var curModel = groups[ i ].children[ 0 ];
            // create a new instance of our new Model
            var newModel = Ext.create('GroupedResult');
                // set the property in the model that corresponds to our xField config
                newModel.set( me.xField, curModel.get( me.xField ) );
            // now loop over each of the records within the old store's current group
            for( var x in groups[ i ].children ) {
                // get the record
                var dataModel = groups[ i ].children[ x ];
                // get the property and value that correspond to gField AND yField
                var dataProperty = dataModel.get( me.gField );
                var dataValue = dataModel.get( me.yField );
                // update the value for the property in the Model instance
                newModel.set( dataProperty, dataValue ); 
                // add the Model instance to the new Store
                newStore.add( newModel );
            }
        }
        // now we have to fix the axes so they work
        // for each axes...
        me.chart.axes.each( function( item, index, len ) {
            // if array of fields
            if( typeof item.fields=='object' ) {
                // loop over the axis' fields
                for( var i in item.fields ) {
                    // if the field matches the yField config, remove the old field and replace with the grouping fields
                    if( item.fields[ i ]==me.yField ) {
                       Ext.Array.erase( item.fields, i, 1 );
                       Ext.Array.insert( item.fields, i, groupers );
                       break;
                    }
                } 
            }
            // if simple string
            else {
                // if field matches the yField config, overwrite with grouping fields (string or array)
                if( item.fields==me.yField ) {
                    item.fields = groupers;
                }
            }
        });
        // set series fields and yField config to the new groupers
        me.fields,me.yField = groupers;
        // update chart's store config, and re-bind the store
        me.chart.store = newStore;
        me.chart.bindStore( me.chart.store, true );
        // done!
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

initComponent exists only in `Components`. If you want to extend a class that does not inherit from Ext.Component, you have to use constructor.

Generally, it is neither better or worse to use constructor, initComponent is preferred (for Components descendants) only because it runs when many tasks the constructor does are already done so it is easier.

For more details, study the [constructor of AbstractComponent](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/AbstractComponent.html#Ext-AbstractComponent).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. can you show me what changes do I need to make to run the same example with initComponent....

Comment: You cannot. Ext.chart.series.Column does not extend Component.